# Put element inline with pagination button from datatables

Tags: html, css, datatables

i want to put "COMPARE and SAVE LAYOUT" button is inline with the pagination button ?  here i was tried using margin but doesn't work
here i use datatable
[here is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETBSJ.png)

here is my table and button code :

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped nowrap dataTable" id="sparepart_id" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                <colgroup span="7" width="85"></colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">PART NO</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">REVISED NO</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">LATEST NO</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">DESCRIPTION</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">INCOMING DATE (FIFO)</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">UNIT PRICE FOB JAPAN</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">MIN ORDER QTY</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">MASTER KEY1</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">TOTAL STOCK QTY</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">STOCK J</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">STOCK B</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">STOCK S</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">STOCK X</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">STORAGE</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">LAST OPNAME</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">DISCONTINUED</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">MESIN</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">SRP STANDARD RETAIL PRICE</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">SRP CASH ON DELIVERY (COD)</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">SUPERVISOR PRICE (COD)</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">MANAGER PRICE (COD)</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">DIRECTOR PRICE (COD)</th>
                        <th class="table-conf header-table">NOTE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="sparepart_data"></tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-primary form-input" style="border-radius: 10px;font-size:13px;" type="button">COMPARE</button></a> <input id="btn_user_filter" name="btn_user_filter" type="hidden"> <button class="btn btn-default form-input" data-filtertype="user" style="border-radius: 10px;font-size:13px;" type="button">Save Layout</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add in your question what datatables library you are using?

Comment: what do u mean ? is the version ?

Comment: I mean that you should link to the datatables project. There are several datatables libraries/plugins, [the jQuery one, the yui one,](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=datatables&atb=v122-6&ia=software).... Tagging `datatables` to your question puts the responsibility on anyone willing to help to first try and determine what datatables library or plugin you're writing about. Try to be clear on this by updating your question. And yes to your question, but it'll be more helpful that your update isn't limited to the version of the library. You can include a link to the library itself